# Qt: Update an area of qwidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I have a problem, need some helps.
I have a Qwidget that have paint event, assume I have 3 areas on my qwidget are area 1, area 2 and area 3. I want to repaint only area 2 and area 3(not repaint area 1) when I call update or repaint of Qwidget. How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

There is `QWidget::update(int x, int y, int w, int h)` function. According to [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#update-1) it:

> This is an overloaded
>   function. This version updates a rectangle (x, y, w, h) inside the
>   widget.

You can use it to repaint only a particular region of your widget.